# NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Looking the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I see that **NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete** is *"Available in OS X v10.8 and later"* but when I try to use it in my code I have a compilation error. Checking the NSData header I see that this feature is only available in iOS:

```
NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0)
```

I'm making something wrong or the documentation is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the enums as defined in the MacOS 10.8 SDK, I see:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSDataWritingOptions) {
    NSDataWritingAtomic = 1UL << 0, // Hint to use auxiliary file when saving; equivalent to atomically:YES
    NSDataWritingWithoutOverwriting NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0) = 1UL << 1, // Hint to return prevent overwriting an existing file. Cannot be combined with NSDataWritingAtomic.

    NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0)                                  = 0x10000000,
    NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0)                              = 0x20000000,
```

"`NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS`" is a macro that expands to

```
 #define NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
```

The "`__MAC_NA`" bit means "not applicable", which means that the documentation is currently wrong.  This functionality is only available in iOS.

You should file a documentation bug with Apple about this.